# Finding the Last Time a Particular Numpy Array has a Value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have some data, expressed as a Numpy array, that has a sequence that looks faintly like this:

```
np.array([1, 0, 2, 5, 10, 6, 2, 0, 4, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

I would like to know what position the last non-zero value of this array - so in this case, the "2" that occurs at position 15.

What's the fastest and easiest way to do this? I'm possibly generating a large number of these, so my initial plan, which was to iterate over the array, remove the last element if it = 0, then take the length of the resulting array, which seems potentially too slow to be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `nonzero` function -

```
>>> arr1.nonzero()[0][-1]
15
```

Answer (score 4):

With `a` as your array, you could use `np.where` to specify the condition you are looking for:

```
>>> np.where(a != 0)[0][-1]
15
```

This function returns the indexes of array for which a given condition holds (in this case the indexes of all elements which are not 0). (Actually `np.where(a != 0)` returns a one-tuple containing the array so we access it with `[0]`.)

The `[-1]` is the familiar Python notation for accessing the last element of an iterable object.